# From what point on the earth's surface could you view the most UK counties?

Tags: uk, factoids, where-on-earth, geography

Investigating from where you could view the most UK counties is what [prompted my previous question on the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/40628/1264) - I know you can view [up to eight counties from the Malvern Hills](http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2010/may/06/britains-best-views-worcester-malvern), and a number of travel programs I've watched often show points where you can see **insert large number of counties** from but I was trying to find where the *most* are visible from and haven't had any luck via Google.

Comment: (Don't worry, I already know Australia's and I don't care about Canada.) ;)

Comment: Unlike US states, can you clarify if you include ceremonial, geographic, administrative, and shrieval counties? All of them? For example on the A264 east of East Grinstead there are 4. But only if you count West Sussex as a 'county'.

Comment: Looking at the maps it seems like [ceremonial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceremonial_counties_of_England) counties best match expectations of UK counties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Wrekin in Shropshire**...

Shropshire, Staffordshire, Lancashire, Gloucestershire, West Midlands, with Greater Manchester County if you count it as distinct from Lancashire.

> The Wrekin /ˈriːkɨn/ is a hill in east Shropshire, England. It is
>   located some 7 km (4.3 mi) west of Telford, on the border between the
>   unitary authorities of Shropshire and Telford and Wrekin. Rising to a
>   height of 407 metres (1,335 ft) above the Shropshire Plain, it is a
>   prominent and well-known landmark, signalling the entrance to
>   Shropshire for travelers westbound on the M54 motorway.[1] The Wrekin
>   is contained within the northern panhandle of the Shropshire Hills
>   AONB. The hill is popular with walkers and tourists and offers good
>   views of Shropshire. It can be seen well into Staffordshire and the
>   Black Country, and even as far as the Beetham Tower in Manchester,
>   Winter Hill in Lancashire and Cleeve Hill in Gloucestershire.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wrekin

Traditionally (i.e., as a matter of local folklore), the peak gives views of 17 counties, but they are not authoritatively  enumerated like the Wiki...

> Like the Snowdon claim, the seventeen counties assertion has appeared
>   in numerous guidebooks and magazine articles since 1860 and persists
>   up to the present day. On the website answerbank (an online version of
>   the traditional Notes and Queries format; see www.theanswerbank.co.uk)
>   one contributor in June 2008 posed the question 'What are the
>   seventeen counties that can be seen from the Wrekin in Shropshire?'.

http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Snowdon-Wrekin.pdf

Comment: In your PDF link, it lists 20 historic counties determined as visible using http://www.heywhatsthat.com/.

Comment: I would be a really hard sell that Oxfordshire and Yorkshire are actually visible :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see 7 proper counties From Lowbury Hill on the Oxfordshire / Berkshire border:

- Oxfordshire
- lots Buckinghamshire
- Chilterns
- Berkshire watership down
- Hampshire
- Beacon hill
- Wiltshire near Coombe gibbit
- Gloucestershire
- Cotswolds
- Northamptonshire
- Musswell Hill.

Comment: I've tried to edit your answer for formatting, but clearly some of your list is not counties, perhaps commentary or places within those counties? Since there end up being more than 7 in the bulleted list. Please finish the editing process to get the effect you wanted.